# What game was included with Red Hat Linux in about 1997?

Tags: rhel, games

In the late ‘90s, I remember installing red hat off a cd on an old 386 or 486 (might have been Red Hat 6, though I’m far from certain). After a lot of trial and error I found the right settings and got everything working. Eventually, I found the games that were included on the cd, and spent a while playing one of them. It was sort of like first-person shooter gameplay, but was a sprite-based side-scroller.

What was that game?

(I realize that game identification is not usually a linux-stack question, but since the key feature is “on a red hat cd in the late 90s”, here seems the most appropriate)

Comment: You can download iso images (e.g. https://soft.lafibre.info/ ), install them in a VM and see for yourself. 1997 makes it RedHat 5.0 or something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux .

Comment: bsd-games ? http://rpm.pbone.net/info_idpl_2396885_distro_redhat_6.x_com_bsd-games-2.9-2.i386.rpm.html

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Crack Dot Com’s Abuse](https://www.mobygames.com/game/abuse), a side-scroller with separate controls for movement (using the keyboard) and aiming/shooting (using the mouse), which is reminiscent of mouselook in FPSs.

[image: Abuse in-game screenshot showing the protagonist next to an explosion]

Red Hat entered into [a partnership with Crack Dot Com in late 1997](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/press-crackdotcom), to publish new games on Linux, but Crack Dot Com folded a year later without publishing any more games.

Crack Dot Com was co-founded by Dave Taylor, who had ported Doom and Quake to various Unix systems and Linux while at id Software, so it’s no surprise that Abuse was released on Linux too.